# Implementing a query cache in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, query-cache

Does SQLite have any notion of a query cache? For example, if I execute the same query two times in a row:

```
select * from Sales1m group by territory_id;
select * from Sales1m group by territory_id;
```

> Result: 136 rows returned in 6663ms
>
> Result: 136 rows returned in 6745ms

It takes just about the exact same time, even though `PRAGMA cache_size=-1000` (1MB)  is set.

Does the second query benefit at all from the first query? If the answer is no, how difficult would it be to implement the query-cache on client-side? I suppose a naive implementation could use the query-string checksum and the result-set (potentially compressed?), but then it'd also need to invalidate whenever the table(s) are updated.

Comment: Is `territory_id` indexed? That will probably have the most performance impact.

Comment: @Schwern -- no, but it's intentionally not -- I'm trying to play around with the query cache to see how it works in sqlite.

Comment: You can prepare a statement and reuse it multiple times, and build on that to implement your own cache in whatever language you're using to interface with sqlite (some bindings, like the python ones, don't allow this  (but I *think* the python ones already implement a cache)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK SQLite does not have a built-in query cache. You'd have to add one at the application layer, probably by using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) which provides a query cache.

What it does do is cache database pages in memory for faster retrieval. You can adjust the size of this cache with the [cache_size pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size). By default it is 2000 kibibytes (2 megs). Try something larger. For example, 20,000 kb (20 megs).

```
PRAGMA <your schema>.cache_size = -20000
```

Comment: thanks for this answer that's what I was wondering. Could you please explain what a "database page" is?

Comment: @David542 It's the unit of data used internally by SQLite to store things. They're anywhere from 512 bytes to 64K. You can read about all that in the [SQLite Database File Format](https://sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_lock_byte_page).